# jQuery ajax params issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is my code:

```
$('body').on('click', '.update_contact_profile', function (){
            var url = $("#ajaxUrl").val();
            var ids = $(this).closest("div").nextAll(".contact-extra-info").find(".contact-ids").attr("id");
            ids = ids.split("-")
            var contactId  = ids[0];
            var customerId = ids[1];
            var postDataUpdate = [];
            $(this).closest("div").nextAll(".update_elements").find(".value :input").each(function(i, itemVal){
                if ($(this).val()) {
                    postDataUpdate[''+$(this).attr('id')+''] = $(this).val();
                }
            });
            var request = $.ajax({
                url: url,
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    id         : contactId,
                    contact    : postDataUpdate,
                    form_key   : FORM_KEY,
                    customerId : customerId
                }
            });

            request.success(function( text ) {  // replace the ajax_wrapper with the new one
                $(".ajax_wrapper").replaceWith(text);
                $("#contact_form").find('select').selectize();
            });
            request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
                alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
            });
        });
```

My problem is that this var `postDataUpdate` it didn't passed to ajax. On firebug the `contact` doesn't appear. If I do `console.log(postDataUpdate)` before my ajax request i got my array .

So any idea about this ?

Comment: var postDataUpdate = []); is that an extra bracket?

Comment: You have an `)` in your `[])`

Comment: srry the `[])` was a wrong copy paste. Thats not the issue, I updated my post. In the console I got no error messages.

Comment: should be `var postDataUpdate = {};`

Comment: @GeneR can u give me an example ? :)

Comment: @Chester already did. You declared an array but using it like object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`postDataUpdate` should be an object, instead of an array:

```
[..]
var postDataUpdate = {};
$(this).closest("div").nextAll(".update_elements").find(".value :input").each(function(i, itemVal){
    if ($(this).val()) {
        postDataUpdate[''+$(this).attr('id')+''] = $(this).val();
    }
});
[..]
```

Check this snippet:

```js
var asArray = [];
asArray[1] = "foo";
asArray["foo"] = "bar";
console.log("asArray:");
console.log(asArray);

var asObject = {};
asObject[1] = "foo";
asObject["foo"] = "bar";
console.log("asObject:");
console.log(asObject);
```